# Cannot run truffle behind proxy?

Tags: truffle, nodejs, truffle-config

I've installed truffle and related software on my office PC. I've set the proxy server for node.js.

The `truffle init` got the following error. Is it proxy issue?

```
H:\work\eth> truffle.cmd init
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a possible solution here,

[How to manually initialize a truffle project? ("truffle init")](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19718/how-to-manually-initialize-a-truffle-project-truffle-init/23353#23353)

I suspect a duplicate question.