# How to manually initialize a truffle project? ("truffle init")

Tags: solidity, truffle

I cannot run `truffle init` on my company PC. (see [Cannot run truffle behind proxy?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19540/cannot-run-truffle-behind-proxy)).

I used a network sniffer and found that the connection was reset when trying to establish an SSL connection to GitHub. My company firewall seems to try to replace the security certificates and caused the problem.

I guess `truffle init` is trying to clone the scaffold source code from the GitHub? It seems there are only eight files (four of them are mandatory) in four directories. How to manually download them?

Will `truffle compile` and `migration` need to access sites which need SSL?

Comment: Not the best way, but I guess you could truffle init on another machine on a different network, then copy the file over.

Answer (score 3):

Go to this url: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-init-default

And just download it in the format of you choice.

[image]

copy the contents to the destination folder and away you go...